# Shell script error using command find

Tags: bash, unix, script, find

My script is supposed to: recursively look for files and directories whose names contain given strings, using `find`, starting in the current directory. If no arguments are given the message `Missing argument(s)` shall be printed before returning the error code `1` to the shell.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash/
if ["${#}" -eq 0]
  then
     echo "Missing argument(s)"
     exit 1
else
  find .  -name "*$@*"
fi
```

I tried to use this in the terminal, but I got this error: 
`bash: ./myfind: /bin/bash/: bad interpreter : Not a directory`

Why? Is my code correct?

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 6):

You need to delete the slash at the end of the first line. /bin/bash is the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You also need a space between `[` and `"`, and between `0` and `]`.

Bonus: You can simplify `"${#}"` to just `$#` - There's no need to quote a variable which is always going to be a number, and there's no need to use braces unless you've got more than just a single variable within the string.

Comment: Great! thanks!Both these suggestions are valuable!